# Disabling all AVX512 extensions

Tags: gcc, avx, instruction-set, avx512

I need to disable all AVX512 extensions in gcc-compiled code. The reason is that Valgrind chokes on AVX512 instructions. Is there a way to do it with a single flag?

I know how to disable each extension individually (`-mno-avx512f`, `-mno-avx512pf` etc) but this is troublesome because different gcc versions support different subsets of those.

I use CMake. If there is a way to automate the flags with CMake machinery, this would also work for me.

Comment: None are enabled by default, are you using `-march=native` maybe?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, I'm using `-march=native`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: is it officially documented anywhere that `-march=native -mno-avx512f` is guaranteed to also disable AVX512VL, AVX512DQ and so on?  As the OP points out, my answer is right in current GCC but https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: It seems to me that instead of enabling avx512 (march=native) then disabling it, it would make more sense not to enable it in the first place (march=skylake maybe?). If you want some guarantees about mno-avx512f, you need to ask in gcc-land, I am not so familiar with that part.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I do want other speedups that `-mnative` offers. It is not easy to enable them one by one for different CPUs.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `-march=native -mno-avx512f` on a Skylake-SP or Cascade Lake is I think exactly identical to `-march=skylake`.  Possibly a different L2 cache size tuning parameter for the `-mtune=native` part.  However, going forward as more different CPUs come along there won't be easy equivalents; e.g. icelake-client / server both have AVX512 and might have some tune settings different from skylake.  So I'd recommend using `-march=native -mno-avx512f`.  The only case it's a problem for you is when it breaks noisily in cachegrind, so if future GCC changes (unlikely) you can change your build.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes that's what I've ended up with. Frankly I would rather prefer avx512 and everything else just supported in valgrind, but one can dream...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`gcc -mno-avx512f` also implies no *other* AVX512 extensions.**  AVX512F is the "foundation", and disabling it tells GCC the machine doesn't decode EVEX prefixes.

Similarly, `-mno-avx` disables AVX2, FMA3, and so on because they all build off of AVX.  (Because of the way GCC works, `-mavx512f -mno-avx` might even disable AVX512F as well.)

---

e.g. `gcc -march=icelake-client -mno-avx512f` will reject intrinsics for AVX512DQ or AVX512VL instructions and so on, as well as not using them when auto-vectorizing.

Comment: Hmm you seem to be right but is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: I checked https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html but it doesn't seem to mention it.  At least it's documented here, in my answer; I upvoted your question since it seems to not be something you can easily / at all look up elsewhere.